# Sub-Query Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Department**(DepartID,DepName)

**Employees**(Name,DepartID)

What i need is the Count of Employees in the Department with DepName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server` version **2005** or **above**, here is another possible way of getting employees count by department.
.

```
SELECT      DPT.DepName
        ,   EMP.EmpCount
FROM        dbo.Department DPT
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT  COUNT(EMP.DepartId) AS EmpCount
                FROM    dbo.Employees EMP
                WHERE   EMP.DepartId = DPT.DepartId
            ) EMP           
ORDER BY    DPT.DepName
```

Hope that helps.

**Sample test query output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an `outer join` rather than a subquery.

```
SELECT d.DepName, COUNT(e.Name)
FROM Department d
LEFT JOIN Employees e ON e.DepartID = d.DepartID
GROUP BY d.DepartID, d.DepName
```

Comment: Subquery is better and avoids sorting on DepName

Comment: @Magnus Chances are that `DepartID` will be the PK/clustered index key and will not require any sort. Edit: That's a bit of a cop out answer though and interesting general point I'll do some tests.

Comment: I suppose, since you group by both DepartID and DepName instead of only DepName

Comment: @Magnus - SQL Server recognises that if you group by the PK that other functionally dependant columns do not need to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.DepName, COUNT(e.Name)
    FROM Department d
        LEFT JOIN Employees e
            ON d.DepartID = e.DepartID
    GROUP BY d.DepName
```

Comment: This assumes department name is unique. `DepartID` seems a better thing to `group by`

Answer (score 1):

No need for a subquery.

```
SELECT dep.DepName, COUNT(emp.Name)
FROM DepName dep
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees emp ON dep.DepartID = emp.DepartID
GROUP BY dep.DepName
```

Comment: This assumes department name is unique. `DepartID` seems a better thing to `group by`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name) FROM  
 Department AS d, Employees AS e   
WHERE d.DepartID=e.DepartID AND d.DepName = '$thename'
```

Answer (score 1):

And to avoid using a `group by` and save you a Sort operation in the queryplan:

```
SELECT 
    Department.DepName, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Employees 
    WHERE Employees.DepartID = Department.DepartID)
FROM 
    Department
```